# How to filter out all records that have duplicates in SQL?

Tags: sql

Trying to get this result from a table with duplicates

```
red
red
red
blue
green
```

to

```
blue
green
```

Totally omitting all the records that has duplicates and only bringing in the unique records

Comment: something with group by and where count = 1 I would try.

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY and HAVING clause...

```
    select color
    from table1
    group by color
    having count(color) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than just the colours.

> ```
> select *
> from paintmess
> where colour in (
>    select colour 
>    from paintmess 
>    group by colour 
>    having count(*)=1
>    );
> ```

> | id | colour |
> | --- | --- |
> | 4 | blue |
> | 5 | green |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=99b85b7510afa6aaccfaa895363d60fb)*